# Is it possible to send greetings to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to send greetings to Stack Overflow?

If a user wants to participate a Stack Overflow celebration, how it is possible? For example, each year the Stack Overflow team will celebrate the day the site started.

How can a user participate those celebrations?

Comment: @suresh.g If users want to get together to celebrate Stack Overflow, [plan a meetup](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/). We typically have a worldwide meetup day to celebrate Stack Overflow's "birthday" each spring. Users plan events in their local cities, and meet each other offline, in real life. That is entirely separate from the normal operations of SO, and we use meetup.com, another company, to plan it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to contact the Stack Overflow team, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page.

We don't really throw public parties (with an occasional exception like opening a new office), but it's always nice when someone emails us to say hi and/or thanks. :)

If you want to meet other Stack Overflow users, [Laura's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157029/is-possible-to-send-greetings-to-stackoverflow#comment452826_157029) is a good one.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to send private messages to other members of Stack Exchange sites. I think there are multiple reasons for this, the main one being there is no good case for it.

The point of the Stack Exchange is knowledge exchange, and that's public by design. If you need clarification on questions or answers, that's what comments are for.

Comment: So now the question is about direct messaging other users? I thought this started off as some sort of birthday celebration thing....