# How can someone remove a question from his account but not from the site?

Tags: discussion, questions, post-disassociation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)

I know that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157029/187824) was asked by which user. But now, that question is removed from his account but the question is still there with anonymous user. How is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SE employees can disassociate posts from accounts. The main use is to anonymize specific posts, which users can request under the Creative Commons license.

Comment: Good. So can we request by mailing to `team@stackoverflow.com`? or anything else?

Comment: That is the best way, you can also flag for moderator attention, but then the moderators just have to forward this to an SE employee.

Comment: Sorry to mention this but couldn't resist. The account link is visible in revision history, so you should try some other way to anonymize to post :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh - I mailed to team to remove it from revision history.

Comment: @hims056 it's still easy to tell who asked the original question because one of the comments there refers to them by name - maybe you could point that out to the team as well.